# How to get rid of additional ops added in the graph while fine-tuning Tensorflow Inception_V3 model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I am trying to convert a fine-tuned tensorflow inception_v3 model to uff format which can be run on NVIDIA's Jetson TX2. For conversion to uff, certain ops are supported, some are not. I am able to successfully freeze and convert to uff inception_v3 model with imagenet checkpoint provided by tensorflow. However if I fine-tune the model, additional ops like Floor, RandomUniform, etc are added in the new graph which are not yet supported. These layers remain even after freezing the model. This is happening in the fine-tuning for flowers sample provided on tensorflow site as well.

1. I want to understand why additional ops are added in the graph, while fine-tuning is just supposed to modify the final layer to match number of outputs required.
2. If they are added while training, how can I get rid of them? What post-processing steps tensorflow team followed before releasing inception_v3 model for imagenet?

I can share the pbtxt files if needed. For now, model layers details are uploaded at https://github.com/shrutim90/TF_to_UFF_Issue. I am using Tensorflow 1.6 with GPU.

I am following the steps to freeze or fine-tune the model from: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#Pretrained. As described in the above link, to reproduce the issue, install TF-Slim image models library and follow these steps:

```
1. python export_inference_graph.py \
  --alsologtostderr \
  --model_name=inception_v3 \
  --output_file=/tmp/inception_v3_inf_graph.pb

2. python freeze_graph.py \
  --input_graph=/tmp/inception_v3_inf_graph.pb \
  --input_checkpoint=/tmp/checkpoints/inception_v3.ckpt \
  --input_binary=true --output_graph=/tmp/frozen_inception_v3.pb \
  --output_node_names=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1

3. DATASET_DIR=/tmp/flowers
   TRAIN_DIR=/tmp/flowers-models/inception_v3
   CHECKPOINT_PATH=/tmp/my_checkpoints/inception_v3.ckpt
   python train_image_classifier.py --train_dir=$TRAIN_DIR --dataset_dir=$DATASET_DIR --dataset_name=flowers --dataset_split_name=train --model_name=inception_v3 --checkpoint_path=${CHECKPOINT_PATH} --checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits --trainable_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits

4. python freeze_graph.py \
  --input_graph=/tmp/graph.pbtxt \
  --input_checkpoint=/tmp/checkpoints/model.ckpt-2539 \
  --input_binary=false --output_graph=/tmp/frozen_inception_v3_flowers.pb \
  --output_node_names=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

To check the layers, you can check out .pbtxt file or use NVIDIA's convert-to-uff utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run training script -> export_inference_graph -> freeze_graph . This gets rid of all the extra nodes and model can be easily converted to uff.